# I'm currently working on a game however I am trying to make an Else statement but it isn't working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently, I am working on a puzzle roll a ball game on Unity and I've came across a problem with my program I have created a code which provides all the information I need where if the player picks up coins they collected the coin however there is another thing that the player needs to collect and it is the key to the next room. However, I came to a problem where the statement shows that I need a semicolon but when I add the semicolon the entire code is wrong and it doesn't provide a possible answer to my code.

the code string:

```
 void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Coin"))
        {
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            count = count + 1;
            SetCountText();
        }
        else
        **{ (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Key"))**
                other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            count = count + 1;
            Setkeycount();

        }


}
```

Comment: `else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Key")) ...`

Comment: Do you mean `else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Key"))` instead?

Comment: If you have another condition to check, use `else if (someOtherCondition == true) { // code to execute here }`. Otherwise, just use an `else` with no condition: `else { // code to execute here }`

Answer (score 0):

Can not understand this part :

```
 else
    **{ (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Key"))**
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        count = count + 1;
        Setkeycount();

    }
```

Did you mean:

```
 else if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Key"))
   { 
        other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        count = count + 1;
        Setkeycount();

    }
```

Comment: No, what I meant is that if the object isn't tagged as a coin it is tagged as a key and is also collectible when I applied else if it causes the rest of my code to show an error.

Comment: your syntax is incorrect 
if(statement)
{
// things to do
}
else
{
// things to do
}

Comment: I applied this to my code it made it work thank you so much!

Comment: @JesusCruz if this answered your question please mark it as the answer.